# How to change onclick so it works on phone browsers?

Tags: javascript

I am using a button on my webpage to call a javascript function like this:

```
<button onclick=" updateText(); "> Update </button>
```

I want this button to work on both computers, and phone/I-pad browsers. The phone browsers use TAB, not mouse click. 
How should I update the button code so it works on phone browsers as well?
I'm not using jquery
Thanks

Comment: You can use touchstart or touchend events.

Comment: How about using the jQuery library  $('#buttonId').on('click',function(){
      //Place code here
});

Comment: A touch event has associated touchstart and touchend events that are equivalent to a click event with mousedown and mouseup events. See [*MDN—Touch events*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) to get started. You should not have to do anything, a touch will dispatch a click event so the listener is called.

Comment: @DaveNorm—how is that any different functionally from an in–line click listener?

Comment: yeah sorry my bad should have been $('#buttonId').on('touchstart click',function(){ //Place code here })

Comment: What makes you think this code will not work on mobile devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this-

Html-

```
<button id="updateText" > Update </button>
```

Jquery-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#updateText').on('click touchstart', function() {

       //your code

    });
});
```

In Javascript:-

```
         <script>
           var updateTextFunction = function(){
                alert('hi');
           };

        window.addEventListener('load', function(){

            var updateText= document.getElementById('updateText')

         updateText.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){

                e.preventDefault();
                updateTextFunction(); 

            }, false)



        updateText.addEventListener('click', function(e){

                e.preventDefault();
                updateTextFunction(); 

            }, false)

        });


</script>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. This works on firefox and chrome, but IE says object doesn't support this property. on the line: window.addEventListener but I guess there's no IE on android or iphones, so I guess this will work. Many thanks.